# How to integrate PATCH rest api in android?

Tags: android, api, rest, patch

I am integrating rest api in android.There are four kind of services. 1.POST 2.GET 3.PATCH 4.DELETE. I have integrated all using "asynchttpclient" except PATCH webservice. I have checked out all the method but haven't find any method relevant to PATCH in "asynchttpclient".
Can anybody tell me how can I integrate rest api using PATCH method with same library "asynchttpclient" or anything else. I have stuck here and spent 2 day over it but haven't found any solution for that.

Comment: u got any solution for patch??

Answer (score 0):

Android comes with a copy of apache http client 4.x, You can subclass `HttPPost` to make an `HttpPatch` object, or use the `_HttpMethod` option on the query string, similar to how its outlined in this other post. [PATCH example with apache HttpClient](http://developerforums.net/threads/patch-example-with-apache-httpclient.21/)

Comment: it' deleted nothing to redirect